# Laravel Eloquent : How to generate a fake column in a Json response?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have two models: `Uai` and `Information` with an hasOne relationship.

```
Uai (uai_id, a)
Information (uai_id, b)
```

I want to generate a Json response witch contains :

- **all** the `Uai` records
- a "fake" column whitch says `true` if the hasOne Relationship exists between `Uai` and `Information` and `false` if there is no relationship

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance
Paguemaou

**Edit One**
Thanks jedrzej.kurylo for your answer. 
How can I use the `uai_id` of the current row in the `fake column getter` ? I othen use getters and seeters but I never try to use the content of another column. Can you give me an example ?

If I understand, I can use the `fake column name` in a select like others columns name. I am true ?

Answer (score 9):

**Eloquent** allows you to easily add custom field to a model's **JSON** representation.

**Firstly**, you need to define a list of additional fields by defining **$appends** property in your model class:

```
protected $appends = ['fakeColumnName'];
```

**Secondly**, add a getter for the fake column that will provide the value for custom column:

```
public function getFakeColumnNameAttribute() {
    //here add the code that will return custom column's value
}
```